# How to control post back programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem to control post back of the drop down menus in asp.net

[image]

as shown in above snap, if the user types in the textbox both the dropdown boxes should not post back. How can I achieve this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable Product = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM dbo.Product", conn);
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(Product);
            conn.Close();
            drp1.DataSource = Product;
            drp1.DataValueField = "ProductID";
            drp1.DataTextField = "ProductName";
            drp1.DataBind();
            drp1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select Product---", "0"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
protected void drp1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ProductID = Convert.ToInt16(drp1.SelectedValue);
    DataTable Signing = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SigningID, SigningDetail FROM dbo.Signing WHERE ProductID = "+ ProductID, conn);
    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(Signing);
    conn.Close();
    drp2.DataSource = Signing;
    drp2.DataValueField = "SigningID";
    drp2.DataTextField = "SigningDetail";
    drp2.DataBind();
    drp2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select Signing Detail---", "0"));
}
```

my concern is that when user type in something in the text box the values in the dropdown boxes should not get inserted into the transaction table but, the value in the textbox should get inserted. There is an OnClick event on a button which inserts values into the table

Comment: You mean you don't want full page to refresh when specific control (textbox) is changing?

Comment: Since there is no obvious relationship between the textbox and the dropdown lists, the textbox shouldn't trigger any event.
Can you post your code instead of the design time screen capture?

Comment: please edit your question with client side code and please rephrase it since it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you should check the TextBox.Text property, if its empty do your work otherwise just ignore the change.

```
protected void drp1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//Check TextBox first
if(TextBoxID.Text==string.Empty)
{
        int ProductID = Convert.ToInt16(drp1.SelectedValue);
        DataTable Signing = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT SigningID, SigningDetail FROM dbo.Signing WHERE ProductID = "+ ProductID, conn);
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(Signing);
        conn.Close();
        drp2.DataSource = Signing;
        drp2.DataValueField = "SigningID";
        drp2.DataTextField = "SigningDetail";
        drp2.DataBind();
        drp2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select Signing Detail---", "0"));
    }
}
```

of course, you will need to change TextBoxID to whatever ID you gave your TextBox control

Answer (score 1):

for drop down box change the AutoPostBack property

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think you need way to make the drop downs conditionally `AutoPostBack` based on whether there is text in the textbox.

You'll need to use some jQuery magic to make this work. First, set the `AutoPostBack` properties of both your dropdowns to `false` (trust me).

Then at the bottom of the page (or wherever you keep your javascript), add this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var usingTextBox = false;

    function FixDropDowns()
    {
        if (usingTextBox)
        {
            // If they are typing in the text box, then you do not want a postback.
            // So lets make the .change() function handler empty.
            $('#<%= drp1.ClientID %>').change(function() {
                // do nothing
            });
            $('#<%= drp2.ClientID %>').change(function() {
                // do nothing
            });
        } else {
            // They are not typing in the text box, so make dropdown postback.
            $('#<%= drp1.ClientID %>').change(function() {
                __doPostBack('<%= drp1.ClientID %>', '');
            });
            $('#<%= drp2.ClientID %>').change(function() {
                __doPostBack('<%= drp2.ClientID %>', '');
            });
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        FixDropDowns();
        $('#<%= txtTextBox.ClientID %>').on('input', function() {
            var txtValue = $('#<%= txtTextBox.ClientID %>').val();
            if (txtValue == '')
                usingTextBox = false;
            else usingTextBox = true;
            FixDropDowns();
        });
    });

</script>
```

So what this will do is, anytime text is entered into the textbox, the dropdowns will no longer post back. If the textbox is empty though, the dropdowns will post back! I think this is what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: setting AutoPostBack to false should be enough

Comment: @tatigo -- Setting AutoPostBack to False will simply cause it to NEVER postback. If I'm understanding the question, he wants to ALWAYS post back unless the textbox has text in it.

Comment: the question is hard to understand indeed

Comment: @tatigo -- Very hard. My interpretation though is that the postback should be conditional based on whether text is in the textbox. If I am wrong, I will delete my answer, since you are correct that setting `AutoPostBack` to false should fix it up